# Complex contour integral properties

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

Do I understand correctly, that for complex line integrals the properties of common integrals (e.g. Riemann-integrals) cannot be applied? Neither linearity:
$$\int_\gamma \beta \;f(z)dz \not = \beta\int_\gamma f(z)dz$$

Is it true that we cannot do any operations with contour integrals in their initial form and can do that only after curve parametrization when we bring those integrals to a form in which the specified operations can be applied?

Comment: No, that's not true. Line integrals are linear, you have $$\int_\gamma \alpha f(z) + \beta g(z)\,dz = \alpha \int_\gamma f(z)\,dz + \beta \int_\gamma g(z)\,dz$$ for all paths of integration $\gamma$, complex constants $\alpha,\beta$, and functions $f,g$ integrable over $\gamma$.